# How to state-fully share my Java application's data changes among multiple hosts on a local network

Tags: java

I am developing an application in Java that uses a `database` and I want to install it on three computers in the same network and save the changes as if I use it on a single computer.

I want to share my application on the network.

**How to state-fully share** my Java application's data-changes among the multiple hosts on a local network?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do.  What have you tried?  What problems have you run into?

Comment: I want to install my app on the network (3 computers in same local network). what should I do ? do some changes in code or what ?!  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two options are :

1. Develop a web based application and host it on one server. Using browser you can access from any machine from the same network even if you dont have internet connection.
2. Use [JNLP protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html) to launch your applet or desktop/swing based application from a server to any client machine.
3. Keep the application jar if it is a desktop application in a network share folder where user can click and launch the application.

**Note:** Even if you install the jar in three computer it is possible to share data if they are connected to a single database server. But you might need to deploy the jar on each machine separately for future program update.

Comment: I use desktop application.is there any other ways to do without share folder like do something with code